Need a custom log-axis for my ggplot graph
I am trying to create a custom log scale for my line graph in ggplot but I'm trying to make a temperature exceedance graph, similar to the one below, to show the amount of time that the water temperature was at or above a specific temperature.
set.seed(123)
n <- 500
x <- seq(0, 100, length.out = n)
y <- 16 / (1 + exp(-0.2 * (x - 50))) - 8
data <- data.frame(x = x, y = y)



G1 <-     ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
            geom_line() + 
            theme(axis.line = element_line(size = 1, color = "black")) +
            geom_hline(yintercept = 0, lty = "dashed") +
            scale_x_continuous(expand=expand_scale(mult=c(0.01, 0.01))) +
            theme(legend.position = "none",
                  axis.title.x = element_blank(),
                  axis.title.y = element_blank())

Example of a temperature exceedance graph:

I want the x axis to be log style for values 0 to 10 then I want it to be a normal axis for 11 to 100 showing only the values 0,5,10,25,50,75,100. I have tried:
G1 + scale_x_log10((breaks = c(1, 5, 10, 25, 50, 75, 100)))


However my issue is now that the section from 10 - 100 is too compacted, anybody able to assist with this issue?

Does the data  under 10  (x<10) is relevant? By fixing a limit with    scale_x_log10(breaks = c(1, 5, 10, 25, 50, 75, 100),                 limits = c(10,NA)) ,  around half of the plot show the y  main variability.

This question gives an example of creating a custom scale which would make a good starting point. In your case, you will need to think again about what you want, because it doesn't make sense to specify a log scale going down to zero.

I'm not sure this is exactly what you're looking for, but one approach could be to use a shifted pseudo_log_trans() transformation, where we make the region around 50 be linear but the extremes be log-transformed.
Normally, the scales::pseudo_log_trans() function is centered at 0, with the region -1 to 1 being roughly linear and the areas beyond that log-transformed. I shift x to x - 50 so that the transformation happens around values of 50, and undo that shift in the labeling with . + 50. I also adjust the parameter sigma of scales::pseudo_log_trans to 5 (adjust to taste) so that most of the steep part of the sigmoid is linear; the default is 1, which would make only -49 to 51 be linear, which looks weird and doesn't do what we need.
ggplot(data, aes(x = x - 50, y = y)) +
  geom_line() + 
  theme(axis.line = element_line(size = 1, color = "black")) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, lty = "dashed") +
  scale_x_continuous(trans = scales::pseudo_log_trans(sigma = 5),
                     labels = ~scales::number(. + 50),
                     breaks = c(1, 5, 10, 25, 50, 75, 100) - 50, 
                     
                     expand=expand_scale(mult=c(0.01, 0.01))) +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank())



I don't think this is a good idea, but it's not impossible:
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
ggplot()+
  geom_point(aes(x = 1:100, y = 1:100))+
  scale_x_continuous(
    transform = trans_new(
      name = "my_transform",
      transform = function (x) { ifelse (x >= 0 & x <= 10,  log10(x)*10, x) },
      inverse = function (x) { ifelse (x >= 0 & x <= 10, 10^(x/10), x) },
      domain = c(0, 100)
    ),
    breaks = c(0:10, 25, 50, 75, 100),
    labels = label_number(accuracy = 1)
  )

